# StatefulBeanToCsv with Column headers

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I am using `opencsv-4.0` to write a csv file and I need to add column headers in output file.

Here is my code.

```
public static void buildProductCsv(final List<Product> product,
        final String filePath) {

    try {

        Writer writer = new FileWriter(filePath);

        // mapping of columns with their positions
        ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<Product> mappingStrategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<Product>();
        // Set mappingStrategy type to Product Type
        mappingStrategy.setType(Product.class);
        // Fields in Product Bean
        String[] columns = new String[] { "productCode", "MFD", "EXD" };
        // Setting the colums for mappingStrategy
        mappingStrategy.setColumnMapping(columns);

        StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<Product> builder = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<Product>(writer);

        StatefulBeanToCsv<Product> beanWriter = builder.withMappingStrategy(mappingStrategy).build();
        // Writing data to csv file
        beanWriter.write(product);
        writer.close();

        log.info("Your csv file has been generated!");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.warning("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Above code create a csv file with data. But it not include column headers in that file.

How could I add column headers to output csv?

Comment: Better related answers here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203867/opencsv-how-to-create-csv-file-from-pojo-with-custom-column-headers-and-custom

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCSV: How to create CSV file from POJO with custom column headers and custom column positions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203867/opencsv-how-to-create-csv-file-from-pojo-with-custom-column-headers-and-custom)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

ColumnPositionMappingStrategy#generateHeader returns empty array

```
/**
 * This method returns an empty array.
 * The column position mapping strategy assumes that there is no header, and
 * thus it also does not write one, accordingly.
 * @return An empty array
 */
@Override
public String[] generateHeader() {
    return new String[0];
}
```

If you remove MappingStrategy from BeanToCsv builder

```
// replace 
StatefulBeanToCsv<Product> beanWriter = builder.withMappingStrategy(mappingStrategy).build();
// with
StatefulBeanToCsv<Product> beanWriter = builder.build();
```

It will write Product's class members as CSV header

If your Product class members names are

```
"productCode", "MFD", "EXD"
```

This should be the right solution

Else, add @CsvBindByName annotation

```
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByName;
import com.opencsv.bean.StatefulBeanToCsv;
import com.opencsv.bean.StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CsvTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Writer writer = new FileWriter(fileName);

        StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<Product> builder = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<>(writer);
        StatefulBeanToCsv<Product> beanWriter = builder.build();

        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        products.add(new Product("1", "11", "111"));
        products.add(new Product("2", "22", "222"));
        products.add(new Product("3", "33", "333"));
        beanWriter.write(products);
        writer.close();
    }

    public static class Product {
        @CsvBindByName(column = "productCode")
        String id;
        @CsvBindByName(column = "MFD")
        String member2;
        @CsvBindByName(column = "EXD")
        String member3;

        Product(String id, String member2, String member3) {
            this.id = id;
            this.member2 = member2;
            this.member3 = member3;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getMember2() {
            return member2;
        }

        public void setMember2(String member2) {
            this.member2 = member2;
        }

        public String getMember3() {
            return member3;
        }

        public void setMember3(String member3) {
            this.member3 = member3;
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

> "EXD","MFD","PRODUCTCODE"
>
> "111","11","1"
>
> "222","22","2"
>
> "333","33","3"

Pay attention; class, getters & setters needs to be public due to the use of Reflection by OpenCSV library

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This worked. But Is there any way to change the column order? As you can see columns are ordered in alphabetical. I need to customize the order like `"PRODUCTCODE", "EXD","MFD"`

Comment: @Bishan you can add to each member the annotation @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0), position is zero based.

Comment: Can't I use both `@CsvBindByPosition` and `@CsvBindByName`? I have added `@CsvBindByPosition`. Now column order is ok. But column names are missing in output file.

Comment: it seems like you are right, i've been traveling all around the source code, consider open a ticket at https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/feature-requests/

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation

Comment: no problem, if annotations CsvBindByPosition or CsvCustomBindByPosition are present, ColumnPositionMappingStrategy is chosen, which does not generate headers, ColumnPositionMappingStrategy#generateHeader returns empty array

Comment: @Bishan it will be nice if you accept my answer as a solution, there are many and might be more suitable CSV libraries for your product, take a look https://github.com/search?l=Java&o=desc&q=CSV+library&s=stars&type=Repositories

Comment: @Bishan Please have a look at [my answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203867/how-to-write-from-bean-to-csv-using-opencsv-by-specfying-custom-column-headers/46185186#46185186). It shows how to write CSV and have both custom header column names and ordering

Comment: Is there anyway to get the exact name in the CsvBindByName annotation? and not the UPPERCASE of it?

Comment: @Iddo how can i remove the double quotes from the output value ?

Comment: Some solution how to control custom naming and ordering: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58731084/7230670

Comment: this didn't work for me, without the mapper strategy even with @CsvBindByName the header columns are still missing

Answer (score 11):

You can append by annotation

```
public void export(List<YourObject> list, PrintWriter writer) throws Exception {
        writer.append( buildHeader( YourObject.class ) );
        StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<YourObject> builder = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<>( writer );
        StatefulBeanToCsv<YourObject> beanWriter = builder.build();
        beanWriter.write( mapper.map( list ) );
        writer.close();
    }

    private String buildHeader(Class<YourObject> clazz) {
        return Arrays.stream( clazz.getDeclaredFields() )
                .filter( f -> f.getAnnotation( CsvBindByPosition.class ) != null
                        && f.getAnnotation( CsvBindByName.class ) != null )
                .sorted( Comparator.comparing( f -> f.getAnnotation( CsvBindByPosition.class ).position() ) )
                .map( f -> f.getAnnotation( CsvBindByName.class ).column() )
                .collect( Collectors.joining( "," ) ) + "\n";
    }

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class YourObject {

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
    @CsvBindByName(column = "A")
    private Long a;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
    @CsvBindByName(column = "B")
    private String b;

    @CsvBindByPosition(position = 2)
    @CsvBindByName(column = "C")
    private String c;

}
```

Comment: Elegant use of stream.  This seems the best implementation.

Comment: This is the best solution - better than using a CustomMappingStrategy

Answer (score 6):

I may have missed something obvious here but couldn't you just append your header String to the writer object?

```
Writer writer = new FileWriter(filePath);
writer.append("header1, header2, header3, ...etc \n");

// This will be followed by your code with BeanToCsvBuilder 
// Note: the terminating \n might differ pending env.
```

Comment: If you refactor your POJO you'll have to remember to change that line too.

Answer (score 2):

For those who want to use HeaderName and Position together without reading a csv file first.

It's quite easy to achieve using a custom Mapping Strategy.

```java
static class NameAndPositionMappingStrategy<T> extends HeaderNameBaseMappingStrategy<T> {
        public NameAndPositionMappingStrategy(Class<T> clazz) {
            setType(clazz);
            setColumnOrderOnWrite(new Comparator<String>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                    CsvBindByPosition pos1 = getFieldMap().get(o1).getField().getAnnotation(CsvBindByPosition.class);
                    CsvBindByPosition pos2 = getFieldMap().get(o2).getField().getAnnotation(CsvBindByPosition.class);
                    return Integer.compare(
                       pos1 != null ? pos1.position() : 0,
                       pos2 != null ? pos2.position() : 0
                    );
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And in your bean you can now define both annotations

```java
 public static class Product {
        @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
        @CsvBindByName(column = "ID")
        String id;

        @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
        @CsvBindByName(column = "FIELD2")
        String member2;

        @CsvBindByPosition(position = 2)
        @CsvBindByName(column = "FIELD3")
        String member3;
    

}
```

And the Writer should look like this:

```java
builder.withMappingStrategy(new NameAndPositionMappingStrategy<Product>(Product.class).build()
```

This will use the CsvBindByName and CsvBindByPosition together.

(Alternatively you can also just use the HeaderNameBaseMappingStrategy and set the ColumnOrderOnWrite without using inheritance)

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day!
This should be included to opencsv by default.

Answer (score 0):

Use a HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy for reading, then use the same strategy for writing. "Same" in this case meaning not just the same class, but really the same object.

From the javadoc of `StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder.withMappingStrategy`:

> It is perfectly legitimate to read a CSV source, take the mapping strategy from the read operation, and pass it in to this method for a write operation. This conserves some processing time, but, more importantly, preserves header ordering.

This way you will get a CSV including headers, with columns in the same order as the original CSV.

Worked for me using OpenCSV 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom strategy

```
    static class CustomStrategy<T> extends ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<T> {
    public String[] generateHeader() {
        return this.getColumnMapping();
    }
}
```

and on CSV object that you write do not forget to provide both

```
@CsvBindByName(column="UID")
@CsvBindByPosition(position = 3)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score -1):

You could also override the generateHeaders method and return the column mapping that is set, which will have header row in csv

```
ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<Product> mappingStrategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<Product>() {
            @Override
            public String[] generateHeader(Product bean) throws CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException {
                return this.getColumnMapping();
            }
        };
```