# When writing a file produced by opencsv in java how do I create a file with no heading?

Tags: java, opencsv

I'm writing using StatefulBeanToCsvBulder. The file format requires that the header have file meta-data, rather than columns. There are 3 bean types.

```
StatefulBeanToCsv headerCsvBuilder = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer)
            .withThrowExceptions(false)
            .withOrderedResults(false)
            .build();
    headerCsvBuilder.write(outputHeader);

StatefulBeanToCsv csvBuilderTransactions = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer)
            .withThrowExceptions(false)
            .withOrderedResults(false)
            .build();
    csvBuilderTransactions.write(samplesList);
```

How do I output this without printing a header each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the annotation

```
 @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
```

On the bean being serialised.

Comment: I want to generate header and use CsvBindByPosition. any suggestions

Comment: Did you try the format that the question has? That produces a header.

Comment: In Question Format, we have to give the headers name manually right. And I am generating using HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy implemented by my class and i am also using @CsvBindByName(column = "Column Name" ). so i did not . I need Custom column name , custom column order and Headers

Comment: The headerCsvBuilder in this case creates a summary row. Probably not what you are looking for.  More relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46072947/statefulbeantocsv-with-column-headers