# Generate CSV from entity based on columns reordering

Tags: java, spring, csv, opencsv

How to achieve this concept based on generating CSV in case of:

- Ignoring field that am not interested in (Could be obtain in OpenCSV based on MappingStrategy)
- Order columns from the list
  My entity consist of 14 variables (id, number, surname...), for ignoring specific files i used `new StatefulBeanToCsv.withMappingStrategy`and it works properly, but additionaly i have f.e List of Fields/String that correspond to my entity, but generated csv should be exactly same ordered like list.

How to achieve this in OpenCSV, alternetively it could be any other lib

Comment: Implement a custom `MappingStrategy`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203867/opencsv-how-to-create-csv-file-from-pojo-with-custom-column-headers-and-custom) can get you started

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCSV: How to create CSV file from POJO with custom column headers and custom column positions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203867/opencsv-how-to-create-csv-file-from-pojo-with-custom-column-headers-and-custom)